# Accessing a users Google Reader Feeds without his credentials through federated login

Tags: c#, google-reader

Before trying to implement this I would like to know if it is actually possible to access a user's Google Reader Feeds without his credentials through [federated login](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenID) in order to avoid having to deal and secure his credentials.

Does anyone have any experience with this?

Comment: After tinkering a bit with DotNetOpenAuth and knowledge from Martin Doms's excellent article on this matter I was able to get it to work and can thus confirm that this is possible.